# Release Created File

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've got the following code that converts a Base64 string to a PDF file, saves it then tries to open it:

```
//Converts the Base64 data to bytes
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64String);

//Stores the converted Base64 data in the application's Local Resource directory, in PDF format
StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
string fileName = file.pdf";
CreationCollisionOption options = CreationCollisionOption.FailIfExists;

var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, options);
var fs = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream);
dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
dataWriter.DetachStream();
await outStream.FlushAsync();

string pdfPath = folder.Path + "\\" + fileName;

StorageFile fileToLaunch = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pdfPath);
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch);
```

When the file opens in Adobe reader, there is a message saying the file is still in use by another application. How do I get my application to 'release' the file, so Adobe can open it? Please note this is a Windows 8 app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the code to the following:

```
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, options);

        using (var fs = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream))
                {
                    dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
                    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                    dataWriter.DetachStream();
                    await outStream.FlushAsync();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
```

`IOutputStream` extends `IDisposable`, but you're not disposing of the stream. Try changing that section of the code to:

```
using (var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
{
    var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream);
    dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
    dataWriter.DetachStream();
    await outStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but got the same error. I also tried:

`            var outStream = fs.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
            var dataWriter = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataWriter(outStream);
            dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);
            await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
            dataWriter.DetachStream();
            await outStream.FlushAsync();
            outStream.Dispose();

But that didn't work either.

Comment: I've got it now I'll post the answer in a sec, this did help a lot though thanks! :)