# Release file from [IO.File]::Create in powershell loop?

Tags: powershell

I suspect the answer is along the lines of what is outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041854/release-created-file) but I am very much not familiar with C#

I have a loop creating a random amount of files with random file sizes. I do this with the following code:

```
$FileToCreate = "$CurrentFolder\$FileNameString"
[IO.File]::Create($FileToCreate)
$BytesToAdd = New-Object byte[] $CurrentFileSize
(New-Object Random).NextBytes($BytesToAdd)
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FileToCreate, $BytesToAdd)
Set-NewOwner -FullPath $FileToCreate -Username $CurrentOwnerUsername -DomainName $Domain
```

Running this as is generates the following error:

```
Exception calling "WriteAllBytes" with "2" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 'C:\Folder\Path\Random File Name.docx' 
because it is being used by another process."
At line:6 char:5
+     [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($FileToCreate, $BytesToAdd)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IOException
```

Even if I add `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` after the `[IO.File]::Create()` line it still throws the same error. However, if I run each line individually in very quick succession (less than 1 seconds between the lines) it works perfectly fine.

My assumption here is that as long as the code is run in one block the `[IO.File]::Create()` somehow keeps the file handle in memory and won't release it in time for the `[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes()` line, whereas running each line individually releases it after each "run".

Is there any way for me to force Powershell to release the file handle to let me run the `WriteAllBytes()`? I tried to look in the documentation but could not find any suitable function for `[IO.File]`.

Comment: Why bother with `[IO.File]::Create($FileToCreate)` in the first place? Method [WriteAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes) _"creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten."_

Comment: DUUUUUUDE you just saved me so much headache. THANK YOU! If you want to post this as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use `[IO.File]::Create($FileToCreate)` to first create a new file.

As [The Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes) say:

> **IO.File.WriteAllBytes** Creates a new file, writes the specified byte
> array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file
> already exists, it is overwritten.